# Shortest optimized, performing code to check if current menu item is last in the list

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, optimization, time-complexity

In a asp.net menu that does loads of recursion with loads of menu items (in order of 100's) what would be the most performing code i can write to check if the current menu item is the last in the list of items. I came up with this but i would like to improve this, i would mark a code as answer only when they can explain how they their code is optimized and performing.

```
if (childMenuItems.Parent.ChildItems.IndexOf(childMenuItem) == childMenuItems.Parent.ChildItems.Count -1)
```

#### Inputs

childMenuItem  is instance of `MenuItem` which is present in the `Menu`  class

Comment: @sll `IndexOf(childMenuItem)` sorry for the pluralization there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (childMenuItems.Parent.ChildItems[childMenuItems.Parent.ChildItems.Count-1] == childMenuItem)
```

In my opinion, this is optimised because you're doing a straight array index which is cheap rather than doing `IndexOf`.  `IndexOf` is expensive because it starts at the beginning of the list and equality compares each element against `childMenuItem`.

In this solution there is only one equality check which is the most expensive part.

UPDATE This solution assumes that there are always elements in the list

Comment: and yes the list contains elements. Marked as answer